# How to copy a File Explorer Details View to other PCs?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

On a Windows network with Windows Server and Windows 10 clients I want that all users have the same details view in File Explorer with the same columns, column width, sort order, etc.
I am looking for a way to copy an existing view from one PC to others so that I don't have to do the same work on each infividual PC.

I found a tool for this here
https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/32105-folder-view-settings-back-up-restore-windows.html
and this works fine with Windows 8.1. But it does not work for Windows 10.

I did not find anything like that for Windows 10. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want folders to use a common *template*, The easier method would be setting the desired view on a folder on a client machine, then using **View > Folder Options View** tab **> Apply to Folders**. This will set your customized view as the template for that folder *type* (Generic, Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures, and Videos) ---So you have to repeat the customize/Apply six times. These customized templates are stored in the Regsitry as REG_BINARY values under the key:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults
```

The values have GUID names corresponding to the IDs found under:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes
```

With templates set for the FolderTypes mentioned above, you would see:
[image: HKCU...\Streams\Defaults]
This key can then be exported and the resultant .reg file merged to the registry of all the machines.

Concerns:

- Barring a Group Policy setting, users could wipe out your customized templates using the **Reset Folders** button in the **Folder Options** dialog.
- These templates don't override existing saved views for individual folders (**BagMRU/Bags**). So if the machines are currently in use and you want the templates applied to folders that have already been opened at some point (and hence have a **Bags** entry), you would want to delete **BagMRU** and **Bags** on the machines after merging your templates.

---

A second option would be more work, but have the advantages that users could not wipe out templates and you could also customzize folders like **Librares** and **Search Results** --- doing away with that annoying **Content** view!
To do this:

- Export the Regstry key:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes
```

- Open the .reg file in a text editor and replace all occurances of **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE** with **HKEY_CURRENT_USER** and save the modified file.
- Merge the modified file.
- (The 'more work' part) Edit the varous values under the **TopView** subkeys of **HKCU...\FolderTypes**, most notably,
- **LogicalViewMode** (1 = Details)
- **ColumnList** A '0' prefix on a property means it appears by default, a '1' means it is available in the droplist displayed when you right-click a column header in Details view. Column width can be specified by **(##)** between the prefix and the property name: **prop:0(34)System.ItemNameDisplay** Not sure what the units are --- you just have to experiment. But remember when testing to always create a new folder every time you modify the template, as any folder previously opened will use its individual saved view rather than the template.

Don't forget that once you've found your desired settings, a little PowerShell can do the busy work of copying to the other TopVIews.

Once you have all templates set to your liking, the

```
*HKCU*\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes
```

key can be exported & dopied to all the machines.

Comment: I hate when old posts pop up on the Home page! I didn't notice the date until I composed this answer. Oh well, still useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to export the registry keys below from the source machine, and then import them onto the target machine

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU 
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags 
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\Bags 
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\BagMRU 
"HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU" 
"HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags"
```

There is another tool specifically designed for windows 10. It is called Backup_and_Restore_Folder_View_Settings_Tool.bat.

You will find it here: tenforums.com/tutorials/17777-backup-restore-folder-view-settings-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it on one PC and it does not work on that PC. The folder layout is not copied. I checked the details and I found out that I don't have any registry folders HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam  Later today I will try it on other PCs but any info is appreciated.

Comment: Was this PC running Windows 10? Did you try the application?

Comment: Yes, I tried the application and it was Windows 10 with the newest updates. I just tried again using "Run as Administrator" to be sure. But still the same result, it does not work (now tried on two independent Windows 10 PCs) Any ideas?

Comment: you know that HKCU means HKEY_CURRENT_USER right?
Have you also saved some folder configuration for the registry key to be populated?

Comment: My summary on this is that is just does not work. Yes, I know HKCU, I saved the folder configuration, I did this on several Windows 10 PCs, it just does not work. I am a computer professional since the times of Windows 3, it just does not work.